# Removing resource depending on other resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**I have users and projects resources and join table that connects them called project_members.** I wish to have functionality when all users leave the project, the project destroys itself, something like spec below:

```
 75     it 'deletes the project when there are no more users on it' do
 76       lambda do
 77         project.users.clear 
 78       end.should change(Project, :count).by(-1)
 79     end
```

So far I came up with this line but don't know where to put it...

```
@project.destroy if @project.users.empty?
```

EDIT: here are my models

**User model (I'm using Devise)**

```
  1 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  2 
  3   has_many :synapses #aka project_members      
  4   has_many :projects, :through => :synapses
  5 
  6   # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  7   # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  8   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
  9          :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
 10          :confirmable      
 11   
 12   # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
 13   attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
 14 end
```

**Project model**

```
  1 class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  2 
  3   has_many :synapses
  4   has_many :users, :through => :synapses, :dependent => :nullify
  5   has_many :tasks, :dependent => :destroy
  6 
  7   #use this when you don't have callbacks
  8   #has_many :tasks, :dependent => :delete_all
  9 
 10   validates :name, :presence => true,
 11             :uniqueness => true
 12   validates :description, :presence => true
 13 
 14   attr_accessible :name, :description
 15 
 16 end
```

**Synapses model AKA (project members)**

```
  1 class Synapse < ActiveRecord::Base
  2 
  3   belongs_to  :user,
  4               :class_name => 'User',          
  5               :foreign_key => 'user_id'       
  6   belongs_to  :project,
  7               :class_name => 'Project',       
  8               :foreign_key => 'project_id'    
  9   
 10 end
```

**Tasks model**

```
  1 class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  2 
  3   belongs_to :project
  4   belongs_to :user
  5 
  6   validates :name, :presence => true
  7   validates :description, :presence => true,
  8                           :length => { :minimum => 10 }
  9 
 10   attr_accessible :name, :description
 11 
 12 end
```

Comment: Can you please add a description of how the three models all work together? Are you using `has_and_belongs_to_many` or `has_many, :through` to connect users and projects?

Comment: just added them. I think they are not the best and that they could be improved. any suggestion that comes to mind is welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A callback on the membership model should do it:

```
class ProjectMember < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_destroy :remove_project_if_last_member
  private
    def remove_project_if_last_member
      project.destroy if project.users.empty?
    end
end
```

Comment: after_destroy? I dont want to destroy the users, just wish to destroy the links between users and projects... When there are no links, project should get destroyed. But I think this is on the right track, maybe before_delete callback in project model?

Comment: @oFca How about on the ProjectMember class? Answer edited to reflect.

Comment: maybe... added my models into question so you can see exactly what you're dealing with. also I think they need a bit of work, so if you notice any suggestion, let me know :)

Comment: it isn't working. still saying the project count didn't change. Maybe that is because this 'project' is undefined and returns nil? If so, how to assign it properly?

Comment: @oFca if Synapse belongs_to :project, then project should always be defined.

Comment: yeah... i think that the problem is in the spec now... i need to destroy that array, not clear it... how to do it? :)

Comment: @oFca I think `project.synapses.destroy_all` would do it.

Answer (score 1):

First off, your relationship statements can be simplified:

```
belongs_to  :user,
  :class_name => 'User',          
  :foreign_key => 'user_id'
```

Can become simply

```
belongs_to  :user
```

The `:class_name` and `:foreign_key` attributes default as you have them anyway.

You should put a callback on the Synapses class to destroy the Project if the last User leaves it. Something like this:

```
class Synapse < ActiveRecord::Base

  after_destroy :remove_project_if_last_member

  private

  def remove_project_if_last_member
    project.destroy if project.users.empty?
  end

end
```

[Note: I copied the after_destroy callback from another answer -- no sense in making something up if that one is already good.]